# C++ operator unexpected error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I' m trying to define an operator for a class like this:

file.h

```
bool operator<<(XMLPair *p2);
```

file.cpp

```
bool XMLPair::operator<<(XMLPair *p2)
{
....
}
```

When I try to use it in the main program like this

```
XMLPair *p1, *p2 ;
...
p1<<p2
```

it says

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘XMLPair*’ and ‘XMLPair*’ to binary ‘operator<<’
```

Any idea?

Comment: Shouldn't you use:  (*p1)<<p2;   or  p1->operator<<(p2); ?

Answer (score 3):

`p1` is a pointer; the left hand argument of a member operator has to be an object. So you need:

```
(*p1) << p2;
```

Although it would be more idiomatic for the right-hand argument to be a reference, and only to use pointers when you really need to:

```
// Remove `const` as necessary, if the operator needs to modify either operand
bool operator<<(XMLPair const & p2) const;

XMLPair p1, p2;
p1 << p2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand side must be an object, and not a pointer, try:

```
(*p1) << p2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared pointer to p1, and you call the operator on pointer.
Try to invoke operator on (*p1), instead of p1.